# How can I automate a keynote workflow to flatten slides into image slides for export to .ppt

Tags: applescript, automator

I always design my presentation slides in keynote (because I find it easier and more pleasant to work with), though they often need to be presented on a windows machine running PowerPoint.

In order to avoid issues with fonts, formatting, etc., I always use the following effective workflow:

1. Design the slides in keynote, often using images and text.
2. Export the slides as jpg files to a folder on the desktop.
3. Open a new keynote presentation.
4. Drag the jpg files into the slide navigator. This creates an image slide of each jpg.
5. export the new presentation to a .ppt file.

Is there a way I can automate this workflow?  I'd love to collapse steps 2-5 into a single step!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the AppleScript that does this (work on **Keynote** version **6.2**, not on version **5**):

```
tell application "Finder" to set f to (make new folder) as text -- create a temp folder to export images
tell application "Keynote"
    tell front document
        export to (file f) as slide images with properties {image format:JPEG, compression factor:95}
        set {h, w, fPath} to {height, width, file of it}
    end tell
    tell (fPath as string) to if it ends with ".key:" then
        set newFile to (text 1 thru -6) & ".ppt"
    else
        set newFile to it & ".ppt"
    end if
    set jpegs to my getImages(f)
    set newDoc to make new document with properties {width:w, height:h}
    tell newDoc
        set mSlide to last master slide -- blank
        repeat with thisJPEG in jpegs
            set s to make new slide with properties {base slide:mSlide}
            tell s to make new image with properties {file:thisJPEG}
        end repeat
        delete slide 1
        export to (file newFile) as Microsoft PowerPoint
        close saving no
    end tell
end tell
tell application "Finder" to delete folder f -- delete the temp folder
on getImages(f)
    tell application "Finder" to return (files of folder f) as alias list
end getImages
```

**Important**: 
the slideshow must be already open in Keynote before running the script.

And the slideshow must be already saved, because the script use the path of the front document to save the PPT file in the same folder.

--

Updated: to choose location of the new file

```
set v to ("Volumes" as POSIX file) as alias
tell application "Finder" to set f to (make new folder) as text -- create a temp folder to export images
tell application "Keynote"
    tell front document
        export to (file f) as slide images with properties {image format:JPEG, compression factor:95}
        set {h, w, tName} to {height, width, name of it}
    end tell
    tell tName to if it ends with ".key" then
        set newName to (text 1 thru -5) & ".ppt"
    else
        set newName to it & ".ppt"
    end if
    set jpegs to my getImages(f)
    activate
    set newFile to choose file name default name newName default location v with prompt "Select the folder to save the PPT file"
    set newDoc to make new document with properties {width:w, height:h}
    tell newDoc
        set mSlide to last master slide -- blank
        repeat with thisJPEG in jpegs
            set s to make new slide with properties {base slide:mSlide}
            tell s to make new image with properties {file:thisJPEG}
        end repeat
        delete slide 1
        export to (newFile) as Microsoft PowerPoint
        close saving no
    end tell
end tell
tell application "Finder" to delete folder f -- delete the temp folder

on getImages(f)
    tell application "Finder" to return (files of folder f) as alias list
end getImages
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much. Would it be possible to adapt this to open a dialogue to save the new file somewhere else? Usually I'm directly dropping the new ppt file onto a usb drive.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for helping me sculpt this workflow...it's really useful!